# DB use an excessive amount of CPU - 95%

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-mvc, db2

I am using Spring MVC + hibernate in my application. Application server is IBM WebSphere v7. While restarting and after restart application, **Db2syscs** process makes CPU usage 99% and consumes memory usage about **1,034,352K**. This goes about **10~15 minutes**. I tried increasing the heap size allocated to DB2, which made no difference.

**EDIT**

These are my hibernate properties in spring configuration file. Will adding cache, pool properties make any affect?

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/logincfg</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory
</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup
</prop>
```

Comment: What is the size of your database? 1GB of memory for a database server seems fairly lean for a reasonable size database.

Comment: Could it be long queries problem? Missing some indexes or something like that?

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: Database has no so large size. 9 tables in database.

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie: I am using hibernate so very less queries are written by hand.

Comment: Sure, but Hibernate will not create indexes in the tables right? (I've never used Hibernate to actually create tables by itself) I use Hibernate with MySQL and I create manually indexes to optimize join and where!

Comment: Are you running your application server on the same box as your database?  Could they be fighting for resources?  Granted that it's certainly doable (to an extent), but may not be the best idea for a system under heavy-ish load.

Comment: Yes. Both application server and DB server are on same box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WebSphere** itself handles all pooling and cache level for its Data sources. All JDBC related configurations can be performed through **WebSphere administrative console**. Try using `connection pool datasource instead of XA datasource`. Also check `heuristic hazard in server configuration`. These will decrease load on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on linux, try a monitor such as db2top to determine which query is churning your CPU.

```
 db2top -d <your database name>
```

Comment: I am using windows server 2003